# ElasticSearch toggle between case-sensitive and case-insensitive search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know ElasticSearch is **case-insensitive** by default, and we can use mapping to enforce case-sensitive.

However, my requirement is that I need to toggle between case-insensitive and case-sensitive for a field. How should I approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to index the same field for case-sensitive and case insensitive searches.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

`text` type field uses a standard analyzer (that can be used for case insensitive search) and the `keyword` field uses keyword analyzer(that can be used for case insensitive search)

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {                  // note this
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "john"
}
{
  "name": "JOHN"
}
```

**Search Query for Case sensitive search:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name.raw": "JOHN"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66679730",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "name": "JOHN"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search Query for Case insensitive search:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "JOHN"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result will be**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66679730",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "name": "JOHN"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66679730",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "name": "john"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: How to present this in Java using QueryBuilder?